# Does CppSharp support generating a wrapper for Google Oboe Android Library?

Tags: android, wrapper, android-native-library, cppsharp

I'm not a C++ programmer but would like to use the Oboe library from Google for low latency audio. At the moment I'm using AudioTrack but it's not fast enough.

I'm trying to generate the P/Inoke wrappers using CppSharp. Does that even have support for the libOboe.so file? I've written a Console Application for .Net Framework v4.7.2. Had to set the Platform target to x64 else it wouldn't load the CppSharp.Parser library (invalid format).

It does something but only generates error. Tried changing the ParseSourceFile to ParseLibrary only to result in a NotFound.

Is there any documentation other then what's on GitHub?

Ok, here's the code I copied it from the Examples directory on GitHub from the CppSharp project

```
using CppSharp.Parser;
using cps = CppSharp; // Had to make this change, see below
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace ElectroSpit.CppSharp
{
    class Program
    {
        // This is the library I'm trying to parse

        private static string m_Library = @"C:/Projects/TinyGreenBits/ElectroSpit/ElectroSpit/ElectroSpit.Android/libs/x86_64/liboboe.so";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                ParseSourceFile(m_Library, LanguageVersion.C99);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                Console.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        public static bool ParseSourceFile(string file, LanguageVersion lversion)
        {
            var parserOptions = new ParserOptions
            {
                LanguageVersion = lversion,
                Verbose = true
            };

            parserOptions.Setup();

            // With only the using CppSharp.Parser there is a ClangParser class but it
            // did not have the ParseSourceFile below. So I improvised the 'cps' see above
            // So there are 2 entries for ClangParser. Maybe this ambiguity is biting me?

            var parser = new cps.ClangParser();

            // Changing ParseSourceFile() to ParseLibrary() results in NotFound error
            var parserResult = parser.ParseSourceFile(file, parserOptions);

            if (parserResult.Kind != ParserResultKind.Success)
            {
                if (parserResult.Kind == ParserResultKind.FileNotFound)
                    Console.Error.WriteLine($"{file} was not found.");

                for (uint i = 0; i < parserResult.DiagnosticsCount; i++)
                {
                    var diag = parserResult.GetDiagnostics(i);

                    Console.WriteLine("{0}({1},{2}): {3}: {4}",
                        diag.FileName, diag.LineNumber, diag.ColumnNumber,
                        diag.Level.ToString().ToLower(), diag.Message);
                }

                parserResult.Dispose();
                return false;
            }

            var astContext = cps.ClangParser.ConvertASTContext(parserOptions.ASTContext);

            parserResult.Dispose();

            // Now we can finally do what we please with the syntax tree.
            foreach (var sourceUnit in astContext.TranslationUnits)
                Console.WriteLine(sourceUnit.FileName);

            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

And here's part of the output. It looks as if it sees the library as a text file which the name ParseSourceFile() would suggest. Changing that to ParseLibrary() only results in a NotFound error.

```
Compiler argument: -xc
Compiler argument: -std=c99
Compiler argument: -fno-rtti
Compiler argument: -fms-extensions
Compiler argument: -fms-compatibility
Compiler argument: -fdelayed-template-parsing
Target triple: x86_64-pc-windows-msvc
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 lib\clang\11.0.0\include
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\include
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\atlmfc\include
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt
End of search list.
C:/Projects/TinyGreenBits/ElectroSpit/ElectroSpit/ElectroSpit.Android/libs/x86_64/liboboe.so(1,1): error: expected identifier or '('
C:/Projects/TinyGreenBits/ElectroSpit/ElectroSpit/ElectroSpit.Android/libs/x86_64/liboboe.so(1,8): warning: null character ignored
C:/Projects/TinyGreenBits/ElectroSpit/ElectroSpit/ElectroSpit.Android/libs/x86_64/liboboe.so(1,9): warning: null character ignored
C:/Projects/TinyGreenBits/ElectroSpit/ElectroSpit/ElectroSpit.Android/libs/x86_64/liboboe.so(1,10): warning: null character ignored
C:/Projects/TinyGreenBits/ElectroSpit/ElectroSpit/ElectroSpit.Android/libs/x86_64/liboboe.so(1,11): warning: null character ignored
C:/Projects/TinyGreenBits/ElectroSpit/ElectroSpit/ElectroSpit.Android/libs/x86_64/liboboe.so(1,12): warning: null character ignored
C:/Projects/TinyGreenBits/ElectroSpit/ElectroSpit/ElectroSpit.Android/libs/x86_64/liboboe.so(1,13): warning: null character ignored
C:/Projects/TinyGreenBits/ElectroSpit/ElectroSpit/ElectroSpit.Android/libs/x86_64/liboboe.so(1,14): warning: null character ignored
C:/Projects/TinyGreenBits/ElectroSpit/ElectroSpit/ElectroSpit.Android/libs/x86_64/liboboe.so(1,15): warning: null character ignored
C:/Projects/TinyGreenBits/ElectroSpit/ElectroSpit/ElectroSpit.Android/libs/x86_64/liboboe.so(1,16): warning: null character ignored
C:/Projects/TinyGreenBits/ElectroSpit/ElectroSpit/ElectroSpit.Android/libs/x86_64/liboboe.so(1,18): warning: null character ignored
C:/Projects/TinyGreenBits/ElectroSpit/ElectroSpit/ElectroSpit.Android/libs/x86_64/liboboe.so(1,20): warning: null character ignored
C:/Projects/TinyGreenBits/ElectroSpit/ElectroSpit/ElectroSpit.Android/libs/x86_64/liboboe.so(1,22): warning: null character ignored
C:/Projects/TinyGreenBits/ElectroSpit/ElectroSpit/ElectroSpit.Android/libs/x86_64/liboboe.so(1,23): warning: null character ignored
C:/Projects/TinyGreenBits/ElectroSpit/ElectroSpit/ElectroSpit.Android/libs/x86_64/liboboe.so(1,24): warning: null character ignored
C:/Projects/TinyGreenBits/ElectroSpit/ElectroSpit/ElectroSpit.Android/libs/x86_64/liboboe.so(1,25): warning: null character ignored
C:/Projects/TinyGreenBits/ElectroSpit/ElectroSpit/ElectroSpit.Android/libs/x86_64/liboboe.so(1,26): warning: null character ignored
C:/Projects/TinyGreenBits/ElectroSpit/ElectroSpit/ElectroSpit.Android/libs/x86_64/liboboe.so(1,27): warning: null character ignored
C:/Projects/TinyGreenBits/ElectroSpit/ElectroSpit/ElectroSpit.Android/libs/x86_64/liboboe.so(1,28): warning: null character ignored
C:/Projects/TinyGreenBits/ElectroSpit/ElectroSpit/ElectroSpit.Android/libs/x86_64/liboboe.so(1,29): warning: null character ignored
C:/Projects/TinyGreenBits/ElectroSpit/ElectroSpit/ElectroSpit.Android/libs/x86_64/liboboe.so(1,30): warning: null character ignored
C:/Projects/TinyGreenBits/ElectroSpit/ElectroSpit/ElectroSpit.Android/libs/x86_64/liboboe.so(1,31): warning: null character ignored
C:/Projects/TinyGreenBits/ElectroSpit/ElectroSpit/ElectroSpit.Android/libs/x86_64/liboboe.so(1,32): warning: null character ignored
C:/Projects/TinyGreenBits/ElectroSpit/ElectroSpit/ElectroSpit.Android/libs/x86_64/liboboe.so(1,34): warning: null character ignored
C:/Projects/TinyGreenBits/ElectroSpit/ElectroSpit/ElectroSpit.Android/libs/x86_64/liboboe.so(1,35): warning: null character ignored
C:/Projects/TinyGreenBits/ElectroSpit/ElectroSpit/ElectroSpit.Android/libs/x86_64/liboboe.so(1,36): warning: null character ignored
C:/Projects/TinyGreenBits/ElectroSpit/ElectroSpit/ElectroSpit.Android/libs/x86_64/liboboe.so(1,37): warning: null character ignored
C:/Projects/TinyGreenBits/ElectroSpit/ElectroSpit/ElectroSpit.Android/libs/x86_64/liboboe.so(1,38): warning: null character ignored
C:/Projects/TinyGreenBits/ElectroSpit/ElectroSpit/ElectroSpit.Android/libs/x86_64/liboboe.so(1,39): warning: null character ignored
C:/Projects/TinyGreenBits/ElectroSpit/ElectroSpit/ElectroSpit.Android/libs/x86_64/liboboe.so(1,40): warning: null character ignored
C:/Projects/TinyGreenBits/ElectroSpit/ElectroSpit/ElectroSpit.Android/libs/x86_64/liboboe.so(1,41): error: source file is not valid UTF-8
```

Comment: Did you find: [Use C/C++ libraries with Xamarin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/cpp/)

Comment: Yeah, found that one too. The link to the bait and switch article is broken :-( I'm trying to prevent to write all code by hand which is tedious en errorprone

Comment: Archive.org is your friend: https://web.archive.org/web/20190109052721/https://log.paulbetts.org/the-bait-and-switch-pcl-trick/ but still not sure how helpful. As I'm not sure of your end goal, be aware of the latency implications from the README in this now abandoned wrapper: https://github.com/atsushieno/oboe-sharp Good luck.

Comment: CppSharp is too complex a solution. I'm not going to use it anymore. Too much time lost already. Thanks for responding anyway.